# Form submit is not sending an email

Tags: html

I'm having a problem with hosting24.com and I have a submit form which doesn't seem to be sending the emails no matter what I try.

This is what I've tried

```html
<section id="contact-full-2" class="dark-bg bg-color1 cover-bg" style="background-image:url(images/bg29.jpg)">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="title">Order Service</h2>
        <p class="sep-bottom">Paypal will hold the money until both parties agree to full satisfaction.<br>Lets begin! </p>
        <form action="scripts/contact.php" role="form"  id="contact_form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_name" placeholder="Full name" name="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact_email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Your message or question" id="contact_message" name="message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="contact_submit" data-loading-text="&bull;&bull;&bull;" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Order</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: this the contact.php
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$to = "dontbejello1@outlook.com";
$subject = "Contact";
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message";

echo "Data has been submitted to $to!";
mail($to, $subject, $body);

} else {

echo "4! OH! 4!";

}
?>

Comment: You don't specify a method for your form and the default is GET.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on localhost the mail will go to a folder named MailOutput. If you are using free hosting most of the hosts disable the `mail()` function due to its wide misuse. If you are using a paid hosting service and you have't changed the code from its working condition you may have to contact the host provider. It may be due to some server error. Check if any of the above are applicable to you.

According to your reply. This is because you are using a gmail address in the FROM section of your email. Your server does not allow that to prevent fake emails from being send. So you will have to try the following code

```
 <?php
     $to = "someone@example.com"; 
     $message = $_POST['message']; 
     $body = "From: $name_field\n Message:\n $message";
     $subject = "Contact"; 
     $name_field = $_POST['name']; 

     mail($to,$subject,$body);
 ?>
```

Comment: "Sorry, you don't have permission to send email from this server with a
header that states the email is from gmail.com"

We have implemented a new security feature aimed at keeping our servers off various spam blacklists. Note that from now on all outgoing emails will need to specify correct mail headers and avoid any types of spoofing. If you are using a PHP mailing script - please either do not set any FROM header, or if you need to set one - please specify a return address (FROM header) that corresponds with your domain name.

Comment: so this was the issue but i dont understand what they telling me to do

Comment: Ronald i put that i got an email and the message was blank

Comment: Try this. I have uploaded this to my Google Drive and shared https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2ymdtH341D-SUxYb0YzajRqWjQ/view?usp=sharing